Using Serilog to log at various levels of verbosity across namespaces and classes
I was led to believe that I can set a global minimum level of Information and then in particular namespaces or classes I could bump it up to Debug or even Verbose. This is the code:
using Commons;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Events;
using System;

namespace SerilogTesting
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                    .MinimumLevel.Information()
                    .MinimumLevel.Override("SerilogTesting.Program", LogEventLevel.Debug)
                    .WriteTo.Console()
                    .CreateLogger();

                Log.Debug($"{nameof(Program.Main)} started.");

                var logic = new DoSomething();
                logic.Rain();
            }
            catch
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                Log.CloseAndFlush();
            }
        }
    }
}

and this is the library class
using Serilog;

namespace Commons
{
    public class DoSomething
    {
        public void Rain()
        {
            Log.Information("It is raining.");
        }
    }
}

The expectation is that even though the minimum level is set to Information the Log.Debug statement in Main will still be printed out as per the Override call that should allegedly allow Log calls in the SerilogTesting.Program class to pass through if they are at least Debug level.

Following code works:
            //In namesapce "SerilogTesting" of create a logger which has the source name "SerilogTesting.Program"
            var logger1 = Log.ForContext<Program>();
            logger1.Debug($"{nameof(Main)} started.");

            //Log.Debug($"{nameof(Main)} started.");

If you want to create context for DoSomethings class:
    public class DoSomething
    {
        private readonly ILogger<DoSomething> _logger;
        public DoSomething(ILogger<DoSomething> logger)
        {
            this._logger = logger;
        }
        public void Rain()
        {   
            _logger.LogInformation("It is raining.");
        }
    }

program.cs
            //Install package Serilog.AspNetCore
            var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder => builder.AddSerilog());
            var logger2 = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<DoSomething>();
            var logic = new DoSomething(logger2);

